# How to change context in jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm working on two separate HTML files; file **one** is the main page, while file **two** contains the body of a Kendo-UI pop-up dialog. That pop-up gets used in the main page.

In the Javascript for file **two**, I try to reference an HTML element that is in file **one**. It doesn't work.

Through some debugging, I've managed to uncover the following:

```
// In Javascript of file two.
console.log($("#StartPayrollButton"));
// Output in Firefox console:
Object { context: HTMLDocument → CalendarDetails, selector: "#StartPayrollButton" }
```

Here's what I get when I run the same line **manually** in the console:

```
// Manually run in the Firefox console.
console.log($("#StartPayrollButton"));
// Output in Firefox console:
Object { 0: <a#StartPayrollButton.btn.btn-large.btn-squared-default.blue>, length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → MA0004, selector: "#StartPayrollButton" }
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on? I notice that `context` is different in the results; the first result references file **two**, while the second result references the web page (and therefore file **one**).

But what is context in this context (terrible pun intended)? Can I change context in the code somehow (when using the jQuery selector)?

Edit: I went and found how the dialog is created. It is indeed an `iframe`:

```
// Razor in file one.
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
        .Name("PayrollWindow")
        .Title("Start Payroll")
        .Content("Loading payroll options...")
        .LoadContentFrom("CalendarDetails", "Payroll", new { co = Model.Co, guid = Model.calendarId })
        .Draggable()
        .Modal(true)
        .Iframe(true)
        .Visible(false)
        .Width(800)
        .Height(530)
        .Deferred()
    )
```

Comment: by page, do you literally mean two different pages, asin your dialog is using an iframe?

Comment: use different ids to avoid such confusion like "#StartPayrollButton-one".

Comment: @KevinB I don't know, because I didn't implement this originally. I can ask the developer when he comes in tomorrow.

Comment: you could also inspect element...

Comment: @SaurabhGupta The issue is unrelated to duplicate ID's; The ID is only used **once** in file **one** and it is not used for any HTML elements in file **two**.

Comment: @KevinB I looked at how the dialog is created, and it is an `iframe`.

Comment: then fixing it is going to be a bit more complicated, if at all possible.

Comment: @KevinB I tried setting iframe to false, but the dialog doesn't render properly and there are plenty of errors popping up in the console. Looks like I'll have to sit down with the developer tomorrow to mull it over. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MaxJacob when you try to refer something through jquery selector there are two cases either the element is present or it's not, the way it affects the value returned by the selector is that one contains the element and other does not. But both of them consist of context, where context refers to document i.e whole web page. I am not sure but you might be seeing the case which I just described.

Answer (score 1):

The context is basically the starting point for where it starts searching for a given selector, the equivalent in native JavaScript would be something like

```
var context = document.getElementById('parent'); // the context here is "document"

var child = context.getElementById('child'); // now the context is the "#parent" element
```

In jQuery you'd set context as the second argument to `$()`

```
$(selector, context)
```

meaning the same thing in jQuery would be

```
$('#child', '#parent')
```

Of course, these are just examples, ID's must be unique, so using context for ID's isn't really neccessary, but for some other types of selectors it makes sense to do it this way to only select elements within other elements etc. in fact jQuery's context does the exact same things as

```
$('#parent').find('#child')
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Would it be possible to force the context to be the whole HTML page, instead of just the Kendo-UI dialog?

Comment: I guess that depends on what is calling `$()`, if you can't control how `$()` is called with a given context, you likely can't change it later on.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue by doing the following:

`window.parent.$("#StartPayrollButton");`

Note the `window.parent` that allows the dialog in a separate `iframe` to access the element in the main page.